# Prevent remote access of a web page

Tags: security, jakarta-ee, web

Is it possible to prevent remote access of a web page? 
Let's say I have my page1 (home page) which is obviously accessible anywhere via its url. Then I have page2 (admin page) which I would only like to be accessible from the machine where my web application is deployed.

This may sound like [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/222650/how-to-disable-remote-admin-console-for-websphere-6-1) kind of scenario. Only, instead of the admin console, page2 should not be accessible remotely.

Comment: Are you using the Full or Liberty profile?

Answer (score 0):

Please be more precise what are you using?

I assume that you don't use any framework, so you have only serlvets and .jsp pages.

First,put you adminpage.jsp to WEB-INF folder. Content of this folder is not visible out of your application (without your permission).

Second, create filter that will intercept your requests to servlets (Try to use servlets for all requests, don't use direct links to .jsp pages, because this is only way to add some security. These servlets should be like controllers in MVC). To create `Filter` you need to add class that will implement interface `Filter`

```
 public MyFilter implements Filter {
    ...    
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
                                 FilterChain filterChain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
               if (request.getRemoteAddr.equals("your server address") {
                    filterChain.doFilter(request,response);
               }
    }
    ...
}
```

You see, if IP address  is equal as your server address is, this request will be proceed further. Filter interface has more two methods `init()` and `destroy()` and you can leave them blank. To connect your filter with your servlet add to your web.xml following.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>myFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>fullPackagePath.MyFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>myFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/url-to-the-admin-panel-servlet</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Of course you need to have servlet with url that will forward to the admin.jsp page.